# WPFLocalizationExtension with ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpflocalizationextension

I'm using `WPFLocalizationExtension` for my WPF app.
I have one `ComboBox` for languages selection. Item source is an `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` as below:

- `TITLE_LANGUAGE_ENGLISH` : `en`
- `TITLE_LANGUAGE_VIETNAMESE`: `vi-VN`

This is my xaml code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{lex:Loc TITLE_LANGUAGE}"></TextBlock>
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLanguages}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{lex:Loc Key={Binding Key}}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

When I run the application, it throws me an exeption as below:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Key' property of type 'LocExtension'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject

How can I translate the `ItemTemplate` ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `IMultiValueConverter` together with a `MultiBinding`, so that you don't loose the ability to update the localization on-the-fly.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLanguages}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            <Binding Path="Key" Mode="OneTime"/>
                            <Binding Path="Culture" Source="{x:Static lex:LocalizeDictionary.Instance}"/>
                        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <l:TranslateMultiConverter/>
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And here is the converter:

```
class TranslateMultiConverter : DependencyObject, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length == 2)
        {
            var key = values[0] as string;
            if (key == null)
            {                
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }

            var cultureInfo = (values[1] as CultureInfo) ?? culture;

            return LocalizeDictionary.Instance.GetLocalizedObject(key, this, cultureInfo);
        }

        return values.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The `LocalizeDictionary` will raise a `PropertyChanged` event when the app's language will change causing the `MultiBinding` to refresh the values.

Note that the converter is a `DependencyObject` too. This is to provide the context to the `LocalizeDictionary` when calling the `GetLocalizedObject` method.

Comment: I believe your solution works because I succeeded with IValueConverter. Actually, the question can be closed , but one thing I wonder is whether any built in  WPFLocalizationExtension converter or not. :)

Comment: This is brilliant and the only working solution for localizing DataTemplates I found so far.

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind to the Path `Key` directly. The `TextBlock` at `DataTemplate` points directly to a single `KeyValuePair` object, that you can access the property `Key` directly.

```
<TextBlock Text="{lex:Loc TITLE_LANGUAGE}"></TextBlock>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLanguages}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**Update:**

Maybe you have to add a Converter. Try `WPFLocalizeExtension.TypeConverters.DefaultConverter` or implement a class deriving from `IValueConverter` by yourself.

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <cv:DefaultConverter x:Key="DConv" />
</ComboBox.Resources>
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key, Converter={StaticResource DConv}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: @Redplane: As I wrote, you could solve the last problem by writing your own Converter. My answer fixes the Binding error. You will not need a IMultiValueConverter, because you can get the static passed Culture in the Converter directly.